# How to simulate several voltage sources from one?

Tags: power-supply, voltage

If we have two voltage sources of `1V` each, we can connect them in parallel and in series two ways:

[image]

When connecting in series, we are summing voltage and getting `2V` source. When connecting in parallel we are getting the same voltage but more current.

Now suppose we have one power source of `2V`.

How to simulate two equivalent sources with some schematics? Here this schematics is denoted with "black box":

[image]

It should be possible to connect outputs in each way:

[image]

If I made this way:

[image]

it won't be equivalent to two power sources we had initially, because, for example, if I connect them parallel, I will got short circuit:

[image]

Comment: Your initial statements about parallel and series connections of voltage sources are correct.  However, I can't make any sense of your actual question.

Comment: If you are trying to solve a particular problem, it's probably best to state that problem. Like "Get both 5V and 3.3V from 9V battery". If you're interest is in the general case, that's a big question. With DC-DC switching power converters you can get whatever you want (within some practical limitations), but those are quite a bit more sophisticated than a voltage divider or how you arrange a set of batteries; and probably too big for Q&A format.

Comment: your last sketch is incorrect and obvious not possible to split a supply in half. and put in parallel . But buck regulators can reduce input voltage in half with 50% on ratio and more current than input.

Comment: @Dims  Your title says "simulate", but the rest of the question doesn't mention simulation at all.  Thus, I'm guessing that you want to physically generate several supply voltages from one voltage source (not just simulate that numerically).  If that's the case, then what are the voltages (input and outputs)?  What are the output currents?  What are you ultimately trying to accomplish (e.g. power amplifier, or supply rails for OpAmps, or something else)?

Comment: @OlinLathrop I would like to have electronic device, which resembles the properties of several separate power sources, i.e. their ability to be connected both in series and parallel

Comment: @scanny finally I would like computer to control the distribution of electromotive force; the question is as is

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use this since you can use a dc-dc converter or voltage regulator

Comment: So what is inside these two DC converters? How they perform the thing, which is impossible otherwise?

Comment: Please let me know the required output voltages, max current and input voltage

Comment: Input voltage is `12V` (or whatever you want). And output properties should be controlled by a computer DAC).

Comment: It is still very unclear. You need a power supply that can be controlled by your PC ?

Comment: Not the main power, but the smaller powers it was "splitted" into. Namely, on your picture, computer should control V2 and V3, but not V1.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if if you need a high power voltage splitter an active gnd is made with a DC power amp. Otherwise for low power reference, large equal R values with a cap will do.

It is common to see the V split and buffered by a unity gain Op Amp for low impedance but limited to low current.

Answer (score 0):

Yo cannot do like this unless you use multiple voltage regulators.

The concept is about a common voltage reference point (say ground here)

When you split the supply as in figure one point is v/2 and other is V with respect to ground. 
But you can use this as 2 supplies for completely isolated 2 different circuits.

Use voltage regulators or DC-DC converters to get output voltages (different voltage levels if needed) with respect to a common voltage reference point(ground)

Comment: This is the question. Two separate batteries do not have common ground point, so we can connect them as we want. I would like to have the same in one device.

Comment: Can you use a dc dc converter or voltage regulators ?

Comment: I don't know, I would appreciate an advice :)

Comment: Choose 2 dc to dc converters according to your input voltage output voltage and current. You will get 2 different supplies with common ground then

Comment: I need device doesn't know appriori how it will be connected.